# aws ubuntu instance Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have access to aws ubuntu inance via SSH key.

I am trying to clone my Github or bitbucket repo, but it is always failed fired this error:

```
Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out
```

Even I tried to download something with wget but it is failed.

What is the possible issue for this?

can anyone please help me in this case?

Comment: Is your instance in public or private subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused for a number of reasons please check the following:

- Outbound access for your security group allows access to port 443.
- NACLs have correctly configured to include both port 443 and the [ephemeral ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports).
- Your route tables have been configured appropriately with either an internet gateway (if your host is public) or NAT Gateway/NAT instance (if your instance is private).